# Joining multiple edits in a single undo/redo command

Tags: google-apps-script

My script does multiple `moveTo` operations on `Range`s. All is fine except that once the script finishes each particular `moveTo` is a single undoable operation. So if user decided that this wasn't what he needed he has to undo step by step an unknown (to him) number of times. (Which can be even difficult at times of slow/unresponsive connection and due to lack of descriptions of the commands on the undo list.)

Doing a single `getValues`/`setValues` solves the issue. But only if all the data is on a single sheet (otherwise you have to do multiple `getValues`/`setValues` which returns us to the same problem). Also it seems a bit expensive (especially for large sheets) and problematic with formatting and formulas.

So is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution in code, but your user would be able to "group" the changes by time.  Your script is going to make all those changes in a short amount of time.  You just simply go to the top of those changes and click revert, which would revert all of the changes your script made.

I'm not sure how otherwise the user is going to be able to identify the changes.

You can't pick-and-choose which changes to accept and which to reject when using the Google Docs revert process.

Comment: What do you mean "go to the top of those changes"? Where and how you do that?

Comment: In the spreadsheet, use the File | See Revision History.  Look through the history to find the applicable changes.  Go to the "top" by looking at the timestamps (and user) to see when your multiple moveTo changes occurred.  Revert to the version right before your first moveTo().  Note: your moveTo changes could be consolidated with other changes, in that case, use the "Show more detailed revisions" button.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not very user-friendly. Yet still better than nothing.

Comment: I don't disagree, but you don't have many other options.  Each call using the App Script API to moveTo/setValue(s) is going to make a change in the revision history.